# How do I setup arrays with google charts add rows

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to set up a google scatter chart page from these links...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart
and create data table here...
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#chart.draw

Basically I have the basic demo copy working.
Now I am trying to populate the data table with time and date data like this...
add rows like this...

```
// Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Date');
  data.addRows([
```

// this raw text works
   [22,5],[10,24],[9,5],[10,6],[10,7],[7,8]

// but my var - datetime  from database not working 
  //Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.

datetime
     ]);

If I manually type in this:

[22,5],[10,24],[9,5],[10,6],[10,7],[7,8]

it works.

Now I am trying to query a database - then do a .each loop to get the data...

```
//Query the database...
// query here..
datetime = "";
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
//note: each row comes in from the database like: 
//thedate: "02/17/2018" thetime: "18:00:00"
//then I split to just get basic hour and day
t = value.thetime.split(":")    
d = value.thedate.split("/")    
//and create as numbers
tnum =  parseInt(t[0]);
dnum =  parseInt(d[1]); 
//and add to the datetime var
datetime += "["+ dnum + ","+ tnum + "],"
// there was more code to eliminate last ","
// then the end result var datetime looks something like:
//[22,5],[10,24],[9,5],[10,6],[10,7],[7,8]
```

If I manually paste this into the add rows area - it works, however if just paste the datetime var into the same add rows area. the error says:

Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.

Q: I'm sure I am missing something basic, such as the graph needs numbers that may be showing as strings or my array is wrong or something else. Is there something to change to get the graph to accept my datetime var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you're trying to create an array from a string,
instead, use an actual array, which `addRows` expects...

```
datetime = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  t = value.thetime.split(":")    
  d = value.thedate.split("/")    
  tnum =  parseInt(t[0]);
  dnum =  parseInt(d[1]); 

  datetime.push([dnum, tnum]);
});

data.addRows(datetime);
```

Comment: YES YES YES - You fixed it with datetime.push - that makes sense thanks so MUCH!!!

Comment: Also then I got this Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table) and fixed it by changing - from this data.addRows([ // datetime here ]) to this  data.addRows( // datetime here )

Comment: So sorry for the very long delay getting back to you. I just learned about voting and comments and want to thank you for your efforts.